# How to get everything present in clipboard using VBA code?

Tags: excel, ms-word, hp-quality-center, vba

As of now, I am able to retrieve only text content from clipboard using Data OBJECT despite clipboard having html ,pictures & tables.

How to retrieve everything present in clipboard as-is like tables,html etc basically whatever data got copied to clipboard using ctl+c,the same data should be available like (ctl+v) using VBA code.

Is this possible? If not what are the alternatives available?

When manually we are able to get all contents using ctl+v , why not programmatically we are able to achieve the same?

Regards,srihari

Comment: Most applications have a `Paste` method that will do this...

Comment: Hi Cindy, Mine is "HP Quality Center" application, here I am unable to paste the clipboard copied content using VBA code, manually I am able to paste the content by navigating to the particular field "MEMO" section.

Answer (score 0):

You could use: `SendKeys "^v"` to simulate ctrl+v.

Comment: Hi Pawel, I tried using send keys but instead of pasting content in my application, it is pasting content in excel work sheet itself.

Comment: You would first have to set focus on given element. Can you refer to target application via VBA?

Comment: Hi Pawel, My application is "HP Quality Center" or "HP ALM" its a testing tool, In this application under REQ module, I have to set focus on Requirement description field, but I am not able to figure out how to set focus for this HP ALM REQ description field using VBA code